# Problems with nested if statement formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have in one column age (R2), and I'd like based on age to input into another columns age bands.

The formula I have is:

```
=IF(R2=" ","I Unknown",IF(AND(R2>0,R2<15),"A Under 15",IF(AND(R2>=15,R2<=24),"B 15 to 24",IF(AND(R2>24,R2<=34),"C 25 to 34",IF(AND(R2>34,R2<=44),"D 35 to 44",IF(AND(R2>44,R2<=54),"E 45 to 54",IF(R2>54,R2<=64,"F 55 to 64",if(and(R2>64,R2<=74,"G 65 to 74",if((r2>74,"H 75 and over")))))))))
```

Unfortunately with formula above it isn't working but can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

You just had a few syntax errors, watch the extra brackets. It helps to just paste these into a text editor especially when the formula gets really long.
The other thing to remember is that you don't need to do an AND statement for every step.

```
=IF(not(isnumber(R2)),"I Unknown",IF(AND(R2>0,R2<15),"A Under 15",IF(R2<=24,"B 15 to 24",IF(R2<=34,"C 25 to 34",IF(R2<=44,"D 35 to 44",IF(R2<=54,"E 45 to 54",IF(R2<=64,"F 55 to 64",IF(R2<=74,"G 65 to 74","H 75 and over"))))))))
```

Explanation, first we check if R2 is a real number, if not, say it's unknown.
After that it's just checking the age against each range. At the 3rd IF, we already know that R2 is more than 15, so we just need to check if R2 <=24. Same thing for the next check, no need for AND in every step.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response.

Comment: I pasted the formula you've provided and with change in second if statement as think that was a mistake to below?

=IF(not(isnumber(R2)),"I Unknown",IF(R2>0,R2<15),"A Under 15",IF(R2<=24,"B 15 to 24",IF(R2<=34,"C 25 to 34",IF(R2<=44,"D 35 to 44",IF(R2<=54,"E 45 to 54",IF(R2<=64,"F 55 to 64",IF(R2<=74,"G 65 to 74","H 75 and over"))))))))

But got error that too many statements.

Comment: I just edited it - my excel is in another language so I had to rename the functions back to english. should work now.

Comment: `if(not(sum(r2)), ... ` is better than `if(not(isnumber(R2)), ... ` because a blank cell is true for isnumber.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original problem:

If a value is not 'under 15' in the first clause, you don't have to keep re-examining that condition in the false nest.

```
 =IF(value(R2)<=0, "I Unknown",
   IF(R2<15, "A Under 15",
   IF(R2<=24, "B 15 to 24",
   IF(R2<=34, "C 25 to 34",
   IF(R2<=44, "D 35 to 44",
   IF(R2<=54, "E 45 to 54",
   IF(R2<=64, "F 55 to 64",
   if(R2<=74, "G 65 to 74",
   if(r2>74, "H 75 and over")))))))))
```

I think I got the right number of closing brackets.

Although a table lookup would be better, you could even hard-code the limit values into a basic lookup.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, updated formula and explanation. Works perfectly!

Comment: You really would be better off with a lookup table and vlookup or even a hard-coded lookup formula but that is just too much typing for me now. Perhaps later.

Comment: Here is a formula that uses `IF` to check Unknown, Under 15 and over 75, then `CHOOSE` to look up the rest: `If(value(R2)<=0, "I Unknown", If(R2<15,"A Under 15", If(R2>74, "H 75 and over", CHOOSE(Int((R2-5)/10), "B 15 to 24", "C 25 to 34", "D 35 to 44", "E 45 to 54", "F 55 to 64", "G 65 to 74"))))`

Comment: @Chronocidal - While your formula is valid, a simpler hard-coded LOOKUP or a VLOOKUP to an external table would be easier.

Comment: @Chronocidal - Does CHOOSE round up or down, always round down, always round up or choke on a decimal in R2?

Comment: @Jeeped `CHOOSE` always rounds down, so the `INT` isn't really necessary - I just thought it would make things slightly clearer.

Comment: Of course, you can hard-code a VLOOKUP too: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R1,{1E-99,"A Under 15";15,"B 15 to 24";25,"C 25 to 34";35,"D 35 to 44";45,"E 45 to 54";55,"F 55 to 64";65,"G 65 to 75";75,"H 75 and over"},2,TRUE),"I Unknown")`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to clear that up for everyone,.

Comment: VLOOKUP should be used for an external table; LOOKUP should be used for hard coding values and returns.